# Matching a node based on a sibling's value with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

Having a XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records type="array">
  <record>
    <name>svn</name>
    <record-type>A</record-type>
    <ttl type="integer">86400</ttl>
    <zone-id type="integer">69075</zone-id>
    <aux type="integer">0</aux>
    <id type="integer">xxx</id>
    <active>Y</active>
    <data>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</data>
  </record>
  <record>
    <name>domain.tld.</name>
    <record-type>NS</record-type>
    <ttl type="integer">86400</ttl>
    <zone-id type="integer">xxx</zone-id>
    <aux type="integer">0</aux>
    <id type="integer">xxx</id>
    <active>Y</active>
    <data>domain.tld.</data>
  </record>
  <record>
    <name>blog</name>
    <record-type>A</record-type>
    <ttl type="integer">86400</ttl>
    <zone-id type="integer">xxx</zone-id>
    <aux type="integer">0</aux>
    <id type="integer">xxx</id>
    <active>Y</active>
    <data>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</data>
  </record>
</records>
```

How to match all the `/records/record/name` having as sibling `/records/record/record-type` with the value `A`?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Found it:

```
/records/record/name[../record-type/text() = "A"]
```

Comment: It's [simpler and clearer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31118801/290085) to test `record` before descending to `name`.

Answer (score 68):

*Surprisingly, none of the answers to date on this old question provide the **simplest** XPath solution.*

**This simple XPath**

```
/records/record[record-type = "A"]/name
```

**selects**

```
<name>svn</name>
<name>blog</name>
```

**as requested.**

Answer (score 38):

You can also filter a parent element by its children :

`/records/record[record-type[text()='A']]/name`

Comment: It's [simpler and clearer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31118801/290085) to test `record-type` directly without an additional predicate.