# Searching an XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file like this:

```
<quotes>
  <quote>
    <symbol>7UP</symbol>
    <change>0</change>
    <close>45</close>
    <date>2011-08-24</date>
    <high>45</high>
  </quote>
</quotes>
```

I want to search this document by `symbol` and obtain the matching `close` value, in PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean 'based upon "symbol"'?

NB: Wouldn't hurt to improve your accept rating, if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching a node based on a sibling's value with XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912194/matching-a-node-based-on-a-siblings-value-with-xpath)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 'based upon "symbol"'.

Comment: Based upon the contents of symbol of course. I mean, I'm all for clarity in questions, but this question was really not *that* hard to figure out, if you've dealt with querying XML before. (And yes, I read the question before netcoder edited it.)

Comment: Like netcoder said here. Use XPath. This is like the SQL query syntax, but for XML documents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use XPath.

Using SimpleXML:

```
$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$close = $sxml->xpath('//quote[symbol="7UP"]/close/text()');
echo reset($close); // 45
```

Using DOM:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$close = $xpath->query('//quote[symbol="7UP"]/close/text()')->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $close;        // 45
```

...for numeric values specifically, with DOM, you can do (as suggested by [@fireeyedboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165154/fireeyedboy)):

```
$close = $xpath->evaluate('number(//quotes/quote[symbol="7UP"]/close/text())');
echo $close;        // 45
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I was gonna post a little alternative, but you can add it to your answer if you like: `$close = $xpath->evaluate( 'number(/quotes/quote[symbol="7UP"][1]/close/text())' );` (Which is for DOMXPath of course)

Comment: Here is my code, bur I am having errors `public function getStock($symbol)
 {
  $api = file_get_contents("http://stocks.com");
  $sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($api);
  $close = $sxml->xpath("//quote[symbol=".$symbol."]/close/text()");
  return reset($close); // 45
 }`

Comment: @Cyberomin: `http://stocks.com` does not return a document with the XML structure you have provided in your question. It returns a regular HTML document with no `<quotes>`, `<quote>`, etc... elements in sight.

Comment: You need to enclose `$symbol` in quotes: `$sxml->xpath("//quote[symbol='".$symbol."']/close/text()")`. If you have problems, ask a new question, don't post long code blocks in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can just parse your XML file to an object or an array. Makes it a lot easier to work with in PHP. PHP has `simpleXML` for this, which is enabled by default:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.installation.php

Example:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

foreach ($xml->quotes->quote as $quote) 
{
  // Filter the symbol
  echo ( (string) $quote->symbol === '7UP') 
    ? $quote->close 
    : 'something else';
}
```