# Case insensitve xpath 1.0 in query string

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

This is a followup to [Powershell update xml key value based on other key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206036/powershell-update-xml-key-value-based-on-other-key-value)

I have xml in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <plugins>
  <plugin pluginType="plugin1" polling_internal="2" polling_unit="M" enabled="true">
      <params>
        <add key="Server" value="server1.local" />
        <add key="database" value="DataBaseName1" />
      </params>
    </plugin>
  <plugin pluginType="plugin2" polling_internal="2" polling_unit="M" enabled="true">
      <params>
        <add key="Server" value="server2.local" />
        <add key="database" value="databasename2" />
      </params>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
</configuration>
```

In the original posting, I wanted to search the 'database' key and update the value of the Server key, eg search for databasename1 and update the server value of server1.local to something else.

The original solution xpath was

```
"/configuration/plugins/plugin/params[add[@value='databasename1' and @key ='database']]/add[@key='Server']/@value"
```

I have since discovered that some of the database names are in mixed case, and xpath is sensitive so its not picking up some of the database names.

As this is xpath 1.0, I know I have to use the translate function, but I can't figure out from other examples here on where I have to insert it.

As this is for Powershell, using an external Powershell function to do the conversion is fine, as lone as it doesn't modify the case of the entire file, only the search value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, only `add[@key='database']/@value` is mixed case sometimes? This is how you can use the `translate()` function:

```
"/configuration/plugins/plugin/params[add[translate(@value, 'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz') ='databasename1' and @key ='database']]/add[@key='Server']/@value"
```

This lowercases any uppercased letter in the string value of the `value` attribute. That is, it does not manipulate the XML data in any way, the translation is only applied in the path expression.

Comment: Almost there, thank you. It works perfectly for the example I gave, but not when I apply it to my real xml (what's here has been edited for privacy. Apologies for providing a poor example. The actual database names have underscores in them - so  <add key="database" value="DataBase_Name_2" /> would be accurate. I tried adding underscores to the replace strings, but that doesn't work (it should in my simple brain).

Comment: @ItsNotMyStrongPoint You'd like to remove the underscores?

Comment: Not remove them, just perform a case-insensitive search so that I can find database_name_1 and DataBase_Name_1 with the same xpath.

Comment: @ItsNotMyStrongPoint That's possible already. Did you try? The translation takes any input string and replaces all uppercase characters. Nothing is done to characters that are not listed in the first argument of the `translate()` function. But perhaps you mean you'd like to match both `database_name_1` and `databasename1` with the same expression?

Comment: It works fine against the example xml above, just not against my real xml, which I can't post here. No to the latter question, I want to match exactly, aside from case sensitivity. Would the addition of more keys within a <params> section or the presence of many more <plugins> change the result? (other than finding more matching values, which is the intention). Thanks for your help & apologies for my lack of knowledge!

Comment: @ItsNotMyStrongPoint No, more `plugin` elements would certainly not change the result. More `key` elements is also okay, as long as they do not have the same attribute values as other `key` elements in the same `param`. But again: Why don't you simply try and test this?

Comment: I have been testing, inserting my real xml into the example until it stops working - and I figured it out, the Database key was in the xpath as database, my real xml uses Database, but the example was all lower case. My bad. Thank you again!