# Powershell: not able to read in XML data type to change it correctly

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, command-line

Thank you for taking the time to review this post.

I am attempting to create a powershell script which takes user input, and adjusts an XML file. This XML file is used by an application to configure its server settings to communicate with its server. I want to use powershell to manipulate the server value in the XML file to a new value which would be given by user input.

So far im using an example i found here:

```
[xml]$myXML = Get-Content ./config.xml
$myXML.configuration.appSettings
```

This yields the xml data, however my xml file doesnt seem to be structured with static variables and am having trouble pulling the correct variable into powershell to change it.

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="server" value="SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS" />
    <add key="database" value="DATABASENAME" />
    <add key="email" value="foobar@foobar.com" />
    <add key="purge_dml_older_than_days" value="180" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

My confusion is, based on this XML file, is it creating the variables each time it runs? and if so is it possible to change the parameters before variables are available? Not sure how to approach changing the "SERVERNAME" value from a powershell or command line input.

My current output results in

```
add
---
{add, add, add, add}
```

Is it possible to change the xml file to have static variables with the parameters the app is looking for and continue on?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is confusing. No, you cannot change the output of a file until you edit it (duh!). Your appSettings has multiple children called 'add. Think of them as a collection.You can iterate over them: `foreach ($v in $myXML.configuration.appSettings.add) {$v.value }`

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206036/powershell-update-xml-key-value-based-on-other-key-value).  Could help.