# XPath for element matching global id?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have tried to find example without success

Here an example with an XML doc :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <name>vlabresvsanvc01</name>
    <adapterKindKey>VMWARE</adapterKindKey>
    <resourceKindKey>VMwareAdapter Instance</resourceKindKey>
    <resourceStatusStates>
        <adapterInstanceId>85966e95-1ds5-4551-aecb-d707c9453efe</adapterInstanceId>
        <resourceStatus>DATA_RECEIVING</resourceStatus>
        <resourceState>STARTED</resourceState>
        <statusMessage></statusMessage>
    </resourceStatusStates>
    <resourceStatusStates>
        <adapterInstanceId>95f3530e-a526-4a21-bd92-c0f391a8c2ad</adapterInstanceId>
        <resourceStatus>DATA_RECEIVING</resourceStatus>
        <resourceState>STARTED</resourceState>
        <statusMessage>Trust Established.</statusMessage>
    </resourceStatusStates>
    <identifier>95f3530e-a526-4a21-bd92-c0f391a8c2ad</identifier>
</root>
```

I want only to select the resourceStatus (`/root/resourceStatusStates/resourceStatus`) for the `adapterInstanceId` sibling( `95f3530e-a526-4a21-bd92-c0f391a8c2ad` ) that is equal to the identifier (`/root/identifier`).

I'm in fact wondering if this is possible to express that in XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/root/resourceStatusStates[adapterInstanceId = /root/identifier]/resourceStatus
```

will select `resourceStatus` elements with a sibling `adapterInstanceId` equal to the `/root/identifier`,

```
<resourceStatus>DATA_RECEIVING</resourceStatus>
```

as requested.

See also [Matching a node based on a sibling's value with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/912194/290085)

Comment: HI . Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I was looking for. thanks also for the link